# Entity Framework: Select with sum from joined table

Tags: entity-framework-6

How do i do something like this in entity framework with out an overhead.

select 
p.id,
total = sum(b.beløb)
from
projekt p
inner join budget b on ,,,

Column total doesn't exists on table. I added it to data model, so i can handle the value when present in resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add unnecessary fields to your data model. Use DTO's or ViewModels instead.

Example of how to perform those queries in LINQ:

```
var result = (from a in dbContext.Table
             where a.ID == id
             select new
             {
                  id = a.id,
                  total = a.Budget.Sum(q => q.beløb)
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```